# How to show the following inequality $_2F_1\left(5.5, 1, 5;-x^2\right)>0$?

Tags: analysis, inequality, proof-writing, roots, hypergeometric-function

Consider the function $_2F_1\left(5.5, 1, 5;-|x|^2\right)$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n.$ I want to show that this function is positive. I checked that it does not have any roots so can I conclude the inequality by using continuity in $x$ of the function $_2F_1\left(5.5, 1, 5;-|x|^2\right)$?

Comment: According to the definition in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) it certainly looks like a continuous function to me.  However, how did you determine that the function has no roots?

Comment: Use 15.8.1 here https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8 to transform the above expression and then the expression here https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.13

Comment: Nice response; very interesting reading, thanks.

Comment: @user2661923 sure, np. But do you think that this is enough to conclude the proof?

Comment: I am way out of my depth here.  Reminded of the anecdote of a professor proving a theorem to the world and a few months later revealing a counter example.

Comment: Perhaps a useful comment: Your $_2F_1(\cdot)$ function reduces to $\frac{8 \left(35 x^6-30 x^4+24 x^2+16
   \left(\frac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)^{3/2}}-1\right)\right)}{315 x^8}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\, _2F_1\left(\frac{11}{2},1;5;-x^2\right)=\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{11}{2};5;-x^2\right)$$

As @Aaron Hendrickson already commented,
$$g(x)=\frac{315}{8} x^8 \left(x^2+1\right)^{3/2}\,f(x)=x^2 \sqrt{x^2+1} \left(35 x^6+5 x^4-6 x^2+8\right)-16 \left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-1\right)$$
$$g'(x)=315 x^7 \sqrt{x^2+1}$$ So, $g'(x)=0$ if $x=0$.
$$g''(x)=\frac{315 x^8}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+2205 x^6\sqrt{x^2+1} \implies g''(0)=0$$ So $g(x) \geq 0 \quad \forall x$ and $f(x)$ too.

Now $g^{(7)}(0)=1587600$ so $x=0$ is the minimum.

Answer (score 3):

By http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.2.i and http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6.E1, we have
$$
{}_2F_1\!\left( {\tfrac{{11}}{2},1;5; - \left| x \right|^2 } \right) = 4\int_0^1 {\frac{{(1 - t)^3 }}{{(1 + \left| x \right|^2 t)^{11/2} }}dt}  > 0,
$$
since the integrand is strictly positive for $0\le t<1$.